# Can not ping from one node to another while both nodes connected via an ethernet cable

Tags: networking, 18.04, iptables, routing

I have two ubuntu machines each with two physical NICs. 
I am trying to create a private network between two of them connecting of one node's NIC with the other node's NIC.

In Node 1 when I run

> ifconfig

command I got the following result:

```
dpdk0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 169.254.9.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 169.254.9.255
        ether 54:b2:03:8c:ee:b0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 129.241.200.185  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 129.241.200.255
        inet6 2001:700:300:2211:b98c:4988:f6f8:5ad0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2001:700:300:2211:9c8c:db02:7582:8d7e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2001:700:300:2211:2423:1e11:c231:9132  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2001:700:300:2211:9597:ef3:4f7f:cca7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2001:700:300:2211:e885:dcfc:9e47:e12d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2001:700:300:2211:ad8a:cde9:c572:a371  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::103:3a80:c3f3:918c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 54:b2:03:8c:ee:af  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 5290825  bytes 615071421 (615.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1200850  bytes 188144673 (188.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xdc100000-dc120000
```

In the same Node when I run

> ip route show table local

I got the following result

```
broadcast 10.24.208.0 dev wlp6s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.24.210.207 
local 10.24.210.207 dev wlp6s0 proto kernel scope host src 10.24.210.207 
broadcast 10.24.211.255 dev wlp6s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.24.210.207 
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 129.241.200.0 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 129.241.200.185 
local 129.241.200.185 dev eno1 proto kernel scope host src 129.241.200.185 
broadcast 129.241.200.255 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 129.241.200.185 
broadcast 169.254.0.0 dev wlp6s0 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.8.1 
local 169.254.8.1 dev wlp6s0 proto kernel scope host src 169.254.8.1 
broadcast 169.254.9.0 dev dpdk0 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.9.10 
local 169.254.9.10 dev dpdk0 proto kernel scope host src 169.254.9.10 
broadcast 169.254.9.255 dev dpdk0 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.9.10 
broadcast 169.254.255.255 dev wlp6s0 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.8.1
```

In the same Node when I run

> route -n

I got the following result

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         129.241.200.1   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eno1
0.0.0.0         10.24.208.1     0.0.0.0         UG    20600  0        0 wlp6s0
10.24.208.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     600    0        0 wlp6s0
10.24.210.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp6s0
129.241.200.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eno1
```

And when i run in Node 1 the command

> iptables -t nat -L

I got the following result

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Now when I run the same commands in Node 2 I got this results:

```
ifconfig
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 129.241.200.232  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 129.241.200.255
        inet6 2001:700:300:2211:56b2:3ff:fe8c:f363  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::56b2:3ff:fe8c:f363  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 54:b2:03:8c:f3:63  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4229811  bytes 389612925 (389.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 2278  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 11968  bytes 1677329 (1.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xdc100000-dc120000  

enp5s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 169.254.9.9  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 169.254.255.255
        inet6 fe80::56b2:3ff:fe8c:f364  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 54:b2:03:8c:f3:64  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 5649  bytes 1340080 (1.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 522  bytes 42061 (42.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xdc000000-dc01ffff  

    Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination         

    Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination

ip route show table local
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 129.241.200.0 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 129.241.200.232 
local 129.241.200.232 dev eno1 proto kernel scope host src 129.241.200.232 
broadcast 129.241.200.255 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 129.241.200.232 
broadcast 169.254.0.0 dev enp5s0 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.9.9 
local 169.254.9.9 dev enp5s0 proto kernel scope host src 169.254.9.9 
broadcast 169.254.255.255 dev enp5s0 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.9.9


sudo route -n 
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
129.241.200.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno1


iptables -t nat -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Now when I try to ping from Node 1 *enp5s0* interface 169.254.9.9 None of my packets are recieved and while i try to ping from Node 2 dpdk interface *dpdk0* with IP address 169.254.9.10 I get the output: Network is unreachable.

Note that in both of my nodes I have enabled packet forwarding using the following command:

> sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

I would appreciate any hint of what I am doing wrong. I guess judging by ARP tables these interfaces does not exist as entries at all but I am struggling how to set these entries in my routing table and as a result to be able to ping between two Nodes.

Comment: Is Node 1 dpdk0 connected to Node 2 enp5s0 ?

Comment: Hmm I have been thinking for that because I have not been able to access my office because of the situation with covid but I am sure I let them connected. Unless some repairement have taken place in my office these days. Do u think the main issue should be such physical connection?

Comment: If you want a private connection, then it should connect Private NIC in PC #1 to the Private NIC in PC #2. dbdk0 and enp5s0 are on the same subnet so those are the NICs to use for a private connection. However, I would change the IP addresses outside of 169.254.x.x since 169.254.0.0/16 is used by Windows to show a failed connection. Suggest you use something in 10.0.0.0/8

Comment: You dont need to use routing if you are connecting both nics together, ensure the nics are configured to be on the same ip subnet and use a x-over cable (or hub) to connect them.

Comment: I have a doubt though, why these interfaces are not showed at ip route table? I guess they are supposed to be shown there